# GPS antenna of a phone works even it is placed inside, but why its not working indoor

Tags: gps

Sounds blunder, but trying to figure out how. I have heard its best to have line of sight to sky for GPS receivers to work. But in phones it could be on back side or in the PCB itself (I guess). So how it is getting line of sight since there is obstructions which should be the LCD or the phone casing itself. Even its receiving. But its not working when we get into a room

Comment: "Best" doesn't mean "required".

Comment: *But its not working when we get into a room* Depends on what the house containing the room is made of. Concrete, metals and brick block and reflect the signals. Dry cardboard or wood has little effect. The GPS signals are extremely weak already even on top of a mountain so not much is needed to block the signal.

Comment: "Inside" and "Indoor" environments have a path loss exponent > 2. This does not hurt much, if dimensions (from wave bending point to resonator) are kept tiny.

Answer (score 1):

Line-of-sight should be taken with a grain of salt in this case. If it is taken too literal, it often stops making sense, as is the case here.

First off: line of sight seems to suggest a visible line. But one must keep in mind that materials that are opaque and (almost) impassible to light in the visible wavelengths, might be almost translucent for other wavelengths. Examples of this include how visible light can pass through window glass without significant issue, but low-IR (from thermal radiation) or UV can not! (this is why you can't get a good tan behind a window).

Second: When people say line-of-sight, it usually means that the signal cannot take large attenuation (and/or doesn't work well with reflected signals). The case of your phone and your body present attenuation to the antenna: they weaken the signal (though you might be suprised how little this really is, as many plastics are reasonably invisible to the wavelengths of GPS. This is also why you need a metal can to shield against RF, even if you have a plastic enclosure). But they weaken the signal far less than the walls and ceilings in buildings. In part this could be due to the large amounts of metal one might find in many buildings (rebar in concrete, for example).

Hence the signal strength the antenna receives when it is on the back of the phone but outside, will still likely be many times more powerfull as the signal strength inside of a building, but with the antenna pointed "up".

Comment: So a little clarification..  if we hold a small GPS receiver between the palms it still receives the signals without much problem.. isnt it? Anyway thanks for the explanation..

Comment: It could be. Not all antennas are created equal, nor are all amplifiers in the receiver. All of these can have a very significant impact in how strong the received signal must be in order for it to still function correctly. (the antennas inside a mobile phone are often also very poor in performance because they are designed to operate over a very wide band).